# Get element wise average of multiple arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray that is made up of other arrays all of the same length. For example:

```
array_1 = [[3,5,6.2],
           [2,4.1,10],
           [3,3.5,4]]
```

How can I get averages element wise. So as to return a single array where each element is the average of the respective elements across all the sub arrays in array_1? So it would return:

```
averaged_array = [2.66, 4.2, 6.733]
```

Comment: `np.mean(x, axis=0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to obtain the average for each list in the matrix:

```
averaged_array = np.array(array_1).mean(axis=1)
```

to obtain the average for each column:

```
averaged_array = np.array(array_1).mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Should be `axis=0`.

Comment: `axis=0` returns the average per column